# How to find out to which QTableWidget a QPushbutton belongs to?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I have two `QTableWidgetItems`. Each has multiple `QPushButtons` set as cell widget in it.

Currently, for one `QTableWidget` I am using `self.sender()` to find out the row and column of the button that is being pressed:

```
button = self.sender()
index = self.Table.indexAt(button.pos())
currentRow = index.row()
mydata = str(self.Table.item(currentRow, 2).text())
```

However, I would like to connect the `QpushButtons` of both tables to the same function. So, if I have table A and table B both having the QPushButtons connected to the same function.

How can I then know if a button belongs to table A or table B when it is being clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Matyas Kuti says you can use `parent`. I made an example for it.

```
from PySide import QtGui

class MyTableWidget(QtGui.QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None)
        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Click me', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        self.setCellWidget(2, 1, button)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        button = self.sender()
        print(button.parent() is self)


app = QtGui.QApplication([])
table = MyTableWidget()
table.show()
app.exec_()
```

The output is `True` when clicked on the button. Example is in Python 3.X and PySide but should apply to all Pythons and PyQt as well.

---

edit: In case you did not inherit directly from `QTableWidget` but both `QTableWidget` and the buttons are children of another object, just store a reference to the table in the common parent under a known name (for example "table") and then access like:

```
 button.parent().table
```

Comment: I am not inheriting from `QTableWidget`. Instead, both `QTableWidget` and `QPushButton` are created inside a class inherited from `QDialog`. thanks for your help though

Comment: @Chris But then you can store the table in the parent with a known name and only slightly adjust the code. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If the parent-child relationship is properly set between the button and the table widget (most likely it is) you can use the QPushButton's `parent()` method to access the QTableWidgetItem and use the same function on the item to access the QTableWidget.

Comment: I have tried `self.sender().parent() == QTableWidget`  but the result comes out as `False` eventhough I am clicking the button inside the same QTableWidget